# Regular expression for a double word

Tags: regex, repeat

I am trying to write a regular expression that will detect a word that is repeated twice, e.g.,  `greatgreat` or `appleapple`. I could not find any way to do this, after hours of trying I am posting it here to see if anyone can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this ([example](http://regexr.com?319n6) on RegExr):

```
(\w+)\1
```

If you want to make sure that the whole sting is a doubled word add anchors:

```
^(\w+)\1$
```

For more information see the docs - ["Round brackets for grouping and backreferences"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that I didn't see it before!

Comment: For future reference (and for the benefit of future googlers), these are known as "backreferences."

Comment: How does this work with greedy matching?  For an input like `couscous`, I'd expect the entire string to be matched by the initial `(\w+)`.